# Not able to create agentWork record in test class

Tags: apex, code-coverage

I am working on the test class where I stuck up on the creating the test record.

Trigger Code

```
trigger AgentWork on AgentWork (after insert, after update, before insert, 
before update) {
 if(trigger.isUpdate && trigger.isAfter){
    AgentWorkTriggerHandler.updateCases(trigger.new);
 }
}
```

Handler Code

```
public class AgentWorkTriggerHandler {
    public static void updateCases(List<AgentWork> newList){
        Map<Id,Id> mapCaseIdToAcceptedBy = new Map<Id,Id>();
        for(AgentWork aw : newList){
            String wiId = aw.WorkItemId;
            //if the object is case
            if (wiId.left(3) == '500' && aw.Status == 'Opened') {    
                mapCaseIdToAcceptedBy.put(aw.WorkItemId,aw.UserId);
            } 
        }
        if(!mapCaseIdToAcceptedBy.keySet().isEmpty()){
            Map<Id,User> mapUser = new Map<Id,User>([SELECT ID,Name FROM User WHERE ID IN: mapCaseIdToAcceptedBy.values()]);
            Map<Id,Case> mapIdToCase = new Map<Id,Case>([SELECT ID,Status,Case_Owner__c FROM Case WHERE ID IN: mapCaseIdToAcceptedBy.keySet()]);

            for(Id caseId : mapIdToCase.keySet()){
                Case c = mapIdToCase.get(caseId);
                c.Status = 'In Progress';
                c.Case_Owner__c = mapUser.get(mapCaseIdToAcceptedBy.get(caseId)).Name;
            }
            update mapIdToCase.values();
        }
    }
}
```

Test Class

```
@IsTest
public class AgentWorkTriggerHandlerTest {
    static String prospectRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Prospect').getRecordTypeId();
    static String mdmTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('DOC').getRecordTypeId();

    @isTest
    private static void agentHandlerTest(){
        AgentWorkTriggerHandlerTest.setup();
        Test.startTest();
        //   System.assertEquals([Select ID,WorkItemId,ServiceChannelId FROM AgentWork ],null);

        Test.stopTest();
    }
    private static void setup(){
        Account acclstPrnt = Test_Util.createAccount(false,'AccountDEL', 'Lokhanwala' , 'Mumbai' , 'India' , null);
        acclstPrnt.RecordTypeId = prospectRecordTypeId;
        insert acclstPrnt; 
        Opportunity tstoppty=Test_Util.createOpportunity(acclstPrnt.ID);
        insert tstoppty;
        Case caseRec = new Case();
        caseRec.RecordTypeId = mdmTypeId;
        caseRec.Subject = 'testCase';
        caseRec.Description = 'TTB0333333';
        caseRec.OwnerId =  UserInfo.getUserId(); 
        caseRec.Status = 'Work-in-Progress';
        caseRec.Opportunity__c= tstoppty.ID;
        caseRec.Quotes_Required__c=2;
        caseRec.Existing_Quotes__c='test';
        insert caseRec;
        ID SChannelId= [SELECT Id FROM ServiceChannel Where DeveloperName='Service_Case_Channel' Limit 1].Id;
        User user1 = new User();
        user1.id = UserInfo.getUserId();
        System.runAs(user1){  
            AgentWork awork = Test_Util.createAgentWork(caseRec.Id,UserInfo.getUserId(),SChannelId,true);
            awork.WorkItemId = caseRec.Id;
            update awork;}
    }
}
```

**I am getting Error : System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, The agent's status is not associated with the channel for this work.: [ServiceChannelId]**

Thanks !!

Comment: Do any of these [Google search results](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22The+agent%27s+status+is+not+associated+with+the+channel+for+this+work.%22&rlz=1C5CHFA_enIE720IE720&oq=%22The+agent%27s+status+is+not+associated+with+the+channel+for+this+work.%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.3461j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) help?

Comment: I have tried a lot but no one is able to fix up this issue.

Comment: It seems wierd to me that you can't add AgentWork items to a buzy or offline user. Especially as it seems quite difficult to discover whether a user is active or not. You just have to try and handle the error as best you can. Is there an interface to discover the current status of a user?
Is it possible, for testing, to create an active user - so that AgentWork records can be added during tests?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems that the issue is when updating AgentWork.

```
AgentWork awork = Test_Util.createAgentWork(caseRec.Id,UserInfo.getUserId(),SChannelId,true);
```

The SChannelId that you query and set while creating AgentWork might not be valid for the case status that you specify.

Answer (score 0):

The error that you mentioned is also thrown when the UserId associated with the concerned AgentWork item belongs to someone who has Offline or Busy status at the moment. Adding Agentwork items means populating the Omni-Channel. As intuition suggests, you can't populate a user's Omni-Channel if the user is not online in the first place.

Hope this helps :)
Let me know if it does!

Answer (score 0):

Try this ugly code, it worked for me.

aw is an AgentWork instance created for the test.

```
    for (ServiceChannel sc : [select Id from ServiceChannel limit 10]){
        try {
            aw.ServiceChannelId = sc.Id;
            insert aw;
            break;
        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, 'Service channel with id '+sc.Id+' is invalid');
        }
    }
```